# Continuity basic understanding

Tags: calculus, continuity

I have been asked to figure out if they are continuos or discontinues or left or right con/discon for the point -2. -1. 0. 1. 2. , where the function g(x) has domian[-2,2]. I just do not get it.

As far as I can see from the definition,

-2 is right con, because we are at the left end point and it is right con.

-1 not con.

0 We are at right and, but as fare as I can see it is cont at the left so why is this discontinues.

1. I thought it was the same as point -2 but it is left cont.
2. ???

I basically do not get it, please explain.

[image]

Comment: The function must be both left and right continuous and the two limits must be equal for continuity. Hence not continuous at $0$. It is not continuous at $-1$ as you say.

Comment: Why does my textbook say that it is continuous at -1 then?

Comment: @Any could you explain where it is discontinuity and if it is left and right cont?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function $f(x)$ to be left-continuous at a point $x_0$, it must satisfy two conditions:

1. $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^-}f(x)$ and $f(x_0)$ must exist; and
2. $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0^-}f(x) = f(x_0)$

Similarly for right-continuity, and then to be continuous the function must be both left- and right-continuous. So in your example:

1. $f(-2)$ exists, as does $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(x)$, and they are equal, so it is right-continuous. However, the limit on the other side does not exist (because the function is undefined) so it is not left-continuous.
2. While both the left and right limits approaching -1 exist, they aren't equal to the function at that point, so it is neither left- nor right-continuous.
3. $f(0)$ exists, as do both of the limits, but only the left limit is equal to the function. So it is left-continuous at 0.
4. At 1, it's the opposite situation so the function is right-continuous.
5. $\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-}f(x)$ and $f(2)$ both exist, but they aren't equal, so the function isn't left-continuous at 2. And the function doesn't exist to the right, so it isn't right-continuous either.

One point to note is that because the limits on both sides of $f(-1)$ exist and are equal, there *is* a function that is equal to $f(x)$ in the vicinity of $x=-1$ that is continuous and identical to $f$ except for one point. This is sometimes called a *continuation* of $f$ in the neighbourhood of $x=-1$, although it is more often used in situations where the function is just not defined at that point - for example, the function $f(x) = \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ has a gap at $x=2$ but is otherwise identical to $g(x)=x+2$, so we can call $g$ a continuation of $f$ at $x=2$

Comment: Could you extend on what it means not equal to the function: 2. While both the left and right limits approaching -1 exist, they aren't equal to the function at that point, so it is neither left- nor right-continuous.

Comment: Forget it, I got it! Thank you so much!